# unable to register custom Dll using regasm

Tags: c#, dll, windows-7, agent, regasm

I have a custom dll which used to register in winXP , now i want to use the same in win7 but i am not able to register with regasm .

I get an error saying one of the dependencies  is missing .

Although i have added that expilcitly and it is also added automatically with test agent 2010 ,

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.dll"
```

i tried registering the above assembly manually , but that also was unsuccessfull.Error for this was "No types registered".

Can someone please advise.

Comment: Could you resolve the missing dependencies ?